# Spring.net-ExpressionEvaluator working on the context object's Concrete Type(assuming implicit implementation)

Tags: c#, expression, spring.net

I am trying to use spring.net's `ExpressionEvaluator.getValue` function in the following way:

```
bool retVal = (bool)ExpressionEvaluator.getValue(mailMessage, "Subject.Contains('vijay')");
```

The `mailMessage` object falls into a concrete type of a `IMailMessage` interface which has a `Subject` property in its contract.

Now the issue is `mailMessage` object's class has implemented the `IMailMessage` interface explicitly which is why the `ExpressionEvaluator` is trying to use `ConcreteImplementation.Subject` and is failing since it has to use `IMailMessage.Subject`.

What could be the best way to do this, I certainly dont want to implement implicitly.

Or is there a way to cast within the expression?

Comment: afaik this can't be done; really curious about any solution though!

Comment: related post on spring.net forum: http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?10050-ExpressionEvaluator-Cast-in-Parse-expression&highlight=expression+cast

Comment: yup...i added that, but no solutions yet :(